# How do I structure imports in a powershell module's internals?

Tags: powershell

For example, suppose I have the following structure:

```
/.../foo
  foo.psd1  # the default psd1 created with New-ModuleManifest
  foo.psm1  # invokes script.ps1 by scheduling it to run in the task scheduler
  script.ps1
  src/bar.ps1
  src/biz/baz.ps1
```

And in `script.ps1` I might write:

```
. src/bar.ps1
. src/biz/baz.ps1
```

And in `bar.ps1` I write:

```
. src/biz/baz.ps1
```

---

Ok, now, everything will work when I am debugging locally, invoking from the `foo/` directory there.

The question is: how do I prepare and/or modify these import statements to always work, even when the module is packaged up and deployed?

Note also that they are actually hard linked files to my main development powershell file structure. Ideally, I don't do *anything* to the import statements, if possible. But I am pretty sure that is going to go sideways.

Comment: What I would recommend during the build process of your module, before publishing, you would run a step that merges all `.ps1` files into a single `.psm1` then, if you ever publish the package would only contain the `.psd1` and `.psm1` as its main assets (in addition to `.ps1xml` if it had any). This way you would ensure the module will always load properly but also for big modules the load time is many times faster than if it was split into multiple files. There are many modules that can help you with this process, see https://github.com/PoshCode/ModuleBuilder as an example